# Custom Filter Tag inside For in Template

Tags: django

Im writing a report page, and i need to display data from one table related with another table (foreignkeys...), but when iuse my filter tag to filter one queryset and bring me all data filtered by the element id of my forloop i get errors

Models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    ...
```

TemplateTag

```
from django import template
from .models import Foo, Bar

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_bar_from_foo(self)
    return Bar.objects.filter(foo__id=self.id)
```

HTML

```
{% for fo in foos %}
    {% with bars=fo|get_bar_from_foo %}
       {% for bar in bars %}
           {{ bar }}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dam, i just forget to load my templates tags in template...